# Is there a CSS version of the alphabetic option for canvas text?

Tags: css, canvas, text

When using canvas you can set the textBaseline option to "alphabetic" - which is slightly different to "bottom". Is there a CSS version of this setting?

Comment: `vertical-align: baseline;`?

Comment: Cheers. As it turns out, it won't work because the text in question is absolutely positioned. So is there a way to measure the drop (how far the text should be moved down from its original position) so that I can add/subtract it from the Y coordinate?

Comment: It might be this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics/fontBoundingBoxDescent But I'd need a CSS version of it.